# How do I use an image in my flutter tabbed app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code that displays text and tabs.  But I need an image instead of text.  How can I replace the title text with an image?

```
void main() async {
  runApp(Start());
}

class Start extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //icon: Image.asset('assets/Title_image.png')
      title: ('Title text'),
      theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
         ),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 5,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Image.asset('assets/tabs/image1.png')),
                Tab(icon: Image.asset('assets/tabs/image2.png')),
                Tab(icon: Image.asset('assets/tabs/image3.png')),
                Tab(icon: Image.asset('assets/tabs/image4.png')),
                Tab(icon: Image.asset('assets/tabs/image5.png')),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Title text'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.music_note),
              Icon(Icons.music_video),
              Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              Icon(Icons.grade),
              Icon(Icons.email),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I change the "Title test" to an image?  Interesting issues with the stackoverflow editor.  There was a comment requesting the complete code.  But when I included the complete code, I could not save the edit, it insists more details even though there aren't any.  This is a cause of the failure of too much automation.  It required extra irrelevant words to posy the complete code as requested in the comments.

Comment: your question with the sample code is irrelevent.

Comment: Hi There. You need to be more clear. Where do you want your image ? show the rest of the code. What are currently having, may be add a screenshot. Then explain what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the title parameter passed to MaterialApp and pass an image to the title parameter of the AppBar.

```
void main() async {
  runApp(Start());
}

class Start extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
         ),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 5,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Image.asset('assets/tabs/image1.png')),
                Tab(icon: Image.asset('assets/tabs/image2.png')),
                Tab(icon: Image.asset('assets/tabs/image3.png')),
                Tab(icon: Image.asset('assets/tabs/image4.png')),
                Tab(icon: Image.asset('assets/tabs/image5.png')),
              ],
            ),
            title: **Image.asset('assets/Title_image.png')**,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.music_note),
              Icon(Icons.music_video),
              Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              Icon(Icons.grade),
              Icon(Icons.email),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```